# Restore MySQL table from backup

Tags: mysql

I have created backup of a specific table from my database by using the command below.

```
mysqldump -u root -p db_name table_name > table.sql
```

Is it possible to restore the specific backup table without affecting the data of the rest of the tables? Which means, whatever data from my backup file for my table will be the only one affected?

The reverse will be:

```
mysql database_name < database_name.sql
```

But this is for the whole database. How to do it with table backup alone?

Comment: delete all unwanted data from the backupfile and use the Statement ypu provided for import

Comment: Or you can import the file from temporary DB and then move needed table to proper database. By the way - as I know there are no ability to scrap the table data from sql file without manual file update.

Comment: @Jens and Roman S,  Thanks guys. I think deleting unwanted data from my existing table and insert the data from my backup file will do the job then.

Comment: @JunM It is an extremely bad suggestion to manually remove unwanted data from backup file as this task can be error prone. Especially since you already have the table backup separately. A very good answer has been provided by "Pradeep Reddy" as well as me regarding this

Answer (score 0):

While the answer given by "Pradeep Reddy" is absolutely correct there is another way of doing it as well from inside mysql prompt using the `SOURCE` command.

```
mysql> USE database_name;

mysql> SOURCE /my_fullpath_to_backup_folder/table.sql
```

Answer (score -1):

mysql -u root -p databasename < mytable.sql

Comment: Explain your suggestion

Comment: Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* and *why* this solves the problem. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.